# Labialised /r/ in RP

Tags: english, phonology, phonetics, consonants

Is **/r/** in RP labialised in all positions?

**For example:** In words like real, free, proud, tree, brother, borrow, dream, throw etc.

Is it labialised in all positions (like *intervocalic, post-consonantal* etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This 1999](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/icphs-proceedings/ICPhS1999/papers/p14_1365.pdf) paper summarises it simply in its second section:

> [Gimson](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NYe-QgAACAAJ) says of /r/ in RP British English that “[a]lthough for perhaps the majority of RP speakers the lip position of /r/ is determined by that of the following vowel, some speakers labialize /r/ whatever the following vowel.”
>   Perhaps this labialization of /r/ has become the norm, at least in Standard Southern British English. According to [Roach](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=c6WYoAEACAAJ), in /r/ “it is usual for the lips to be slightly rounded”.

The latest version of Gimson's [still says this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MyYuAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA221).